# scanf in assembly x64_86 scan different value than expected

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I tried to scan input of two integers and the first one doesn't get it right but the second is.

```
.section .rodata # Read only data section.
.align  8   # Aline address to multiple of 8.

format_i:               .string "%d %d"

.text
.globl  run_func
    .type   run_func, @function
run_func:
        mov     $0, %eax             
        push    %rbp                    # Keep stack aligned
        movq    $0, (%rbp)
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    $format_i, %rdi         # Load format string
        sub     $16, %rsp               # Allocating memory in the stack
        leaq    -8(%rbp), %rsi          # Adress to store i
        leaq    -16(%rbp), %rdx         # Adress to store j 
        xorq    %rax, %rax              
        call    scanf 
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi          # Passing the first value of scanf
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rdx         # Passing the second value of scanf
        movq    %rbp, %rsp
        pop     %rbp
```

I entered "2 4", what I get in rsi is 0x7fff00000002 and in rdx 0x4.
How can I make rsi get 0x2 instead?

Comment: Ah sorry, you already changed to integers now. Well, similar problem. You only scanned integers, 4 byte each. You load qwords, 8 bytes each. Use `movl -8(%rbp), %esi` and `movl -16(%rbp), %edx`. You can use `movslq` if you want to sign extend.

Comment: @Jester -- that will zero-extend the values, which is probably wrong if the input number happen to be negative.

Comment: That is correct. Edited. Although the question only asked to make it 2 and 4 :)

Comment: @Jester thank you! it worked

Answer (score 1):

`%d` is for reading 4-byte signed integers on most systems.  So you can either:

- allocate only 4 bytes in the stack frame and load those 4 bytes into %rsi with sign extension -- `movslq -8(%rbp), %rsi`
- use `%ld` or `%lld` format, depending on what your library uses for an 8-byte integer type.

Comment: If you want to work with 32-bit signed values as 32-bit, it's totally normal let the high 32 be zero-extended.  (`mov -8(%rbp), %esi`).  You only need to sign-extend if you want to do stuff like look at the full 64-bit register in the debugger instead of `print $esi` or manually ignoring the high zeros.  Or if your code wants to do math that could overflow a 32-bit result, e.g. multiply two 32-bit values and get a signed 64-bit result.  (Without using clunky one-operand imul.)